# Interstitial Ad returns a null value

Tags: java, android, null, admob, interstitial

I programmed an app named "Trumple Run" for android. Like the name says it is a Jump & Run game and I want to release it soon. Before that I would like to implement Interstitial Ads from AdMob. I followed the official guide for the implementation of Ads but the app always crashes when I tried to show the add. Here is some code from my MainActivity (info: I cut out code which is not relevant for the issue; the method addzeigen() is called from another class)

```
public class Main_activity extends Activity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //Fullscreen
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); //Display größe herausfinden
    V.Bildbreite = metrics.widthPixels;
    V.Bildhöhe = metrics.heightPixels;


    addladen();


    V.v = new View(this);

    setContentView(V.v);

}



public void addladen(){
    mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitial.loadAd(request);
}


public void addzeigen(){
    if(mInterstitial.isLoaded()){
        mInterstitial.show();
        addladen();
    }

}
```

I looked at the StackTrace to find the reason for the issue and this two lines indicated that the interstitial is not yet instantiated (returning a null value).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.isLoaded()' on a null object reference
```

Because of that I added a null checker in my addladen() method to prevent a crash.

```
public void addzeigen(){
    if(mInterstitial != null && mInterstitial.isLoaded()){
        mInterstitial.show();
        addladen();
    }

}
```

But why is my Interstitial object null? Did I not instantiate it in the right way in my addladen() method? I already searched for a long time in the internet but found no solution and asked the AdMob support but they said I should ask here because it is an implementation problem. How do I have to modify my code to make sure that my Interstitial is not null? I would be really happy if you could help me.

Comment: Replace `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712` with your own admob id maybe ?

Comment: The ID I use is the official test ID of AdMob. It is supposed to show test ads. I already used the ID in other apps and it worked. I do not think this is the problem but I will test it. Thank you for your help but I would be grateful if you have other suggestions.

Comment: The error simply say that this line: if(mInterstitial.isLoaded()){
 is called before you instantiated the mInterstitial object that is this line: mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);

Answer (score 1):

create application to when open app, add immidiate load

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
public InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private AppOpenManager appOpenAdManager;
private Activity currentActivity;
private int check = 0;
public AdLoader adLoader;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MobileAds.initialize(
            this,
            new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationComplete(
                        @NonNull InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                }
            });
    appOpenAdManager = new AppOpenManager();
    loadInterstitial(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL_ADS);
}

public void loadInterstitial(String id) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    InterstitialAd.load(
            this,
            id,
            adRequest,
            new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                            new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                    // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                                    // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                                    // show it a second time.
                                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                }
                            });
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                }
            });
}
```

}
then you create class check exception happen when load and open app

```
public class LoadInterstitialAds {
private static LoadInterstitialAds instance;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

public static LoadInterstitialAds getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        return new LoadInterstitialAds();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void openAdsThenOpenActivity(Activity activity, InterstitialAdsListener listener) {
    Application application = activity.getApplication();
    if (application instanceof MyApplication) {
        LoadInterstitialAds.this.mInterstitialAd = ((MyApplication) application).mInterstitialAd;
        if (LoadInterstitialAds.this.mInterstitialAd != null) {
            LoadInterstitialAds.this.mInterstitialAd.show(activity);
            LoadInterstitialAds.this.mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    listener.onStartActivity();
                    ((MyApplication) application).loadInterstitial(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL_ADS);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                    ((MyApplication) application).loadInterstitial(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL_ADS);
                    listener.onStartActivity();
                }

            });
        } else {
            ((MyApplication) application).loadInterstitial(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL_ADS);
            listener.onStartActivity();
        }
    }
}
```

}
create interface listener tothe convenience of calling

```
public interface InterstitialAdsListener {
void onStartActivity();
```

}
and finally, run this code at any where you want to show

```
LoadInterstitialAds loadInterstitialAds = LoadInterstitialAds.getInstance();
        loadInterstitialAds.openAdsThenOpenActivity(getActivity(), ()->{
           // your process
        });
```